# Cloudfront - Failed to contact the origin

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

m.giftsdirect.com has a CNAME record for our CloudFront distribution.

We are getting 503 errors, "Failed to contact the origin." on all of our product urls.

E.g. https://m.giftsdirect.com/catalog/product/4/2/4278_GalwayCr300X300.jpg

However, images not under the root /catalog/product are fine, such as http://m.giftsdirect.com/newsletter/PopUpButtonTIS.png

Can anyone help, or let me know what to do? I disabled/enabled the distribution, but no change.

Answer (score 2):

your ssl certificate is not valid, above wont work with https as origin server cannot get through without not accepting certificate.

cloudfront doesnot do [--insecure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html) attempt.

And below url works as you have http connection.

you can see issue [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=m.giftsdirect.com).

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1) You need a valid certificate for your subdomain m.giftsdirect.com in order to [setup HTTPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#SecureConnectionsHowToRequire). Currently, a wildcard cert for *.cloudfront.net is returned and that won't work for your subdomain.

2) A HTTP 503 error is referring to an issue between the CDN and your origin server. If your origin server does not support HTTPS, you need to ensure that Cloudfront fetches the content via HTTP (not HTTPS). Do the following:

1. Open the CloudFront Management Console and go to your distribution.
2. Navigate to the Origins tab, pick your origin and click "Edit"
3. Edit the "Origin Protocol Policy" to "HTTP Only".
4. Save the changes and wait at least 15 minutes for the change to be active.